# how to use values data-num html attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, this, custom-data-attribute

I want the numbers to increase to tasks in HTML(data-num="").
But my code works only for one data-num. 
The second number does not change.
How to make several numbers change at the same time?

```js
var number = document.querySelector('.numbers'),
  numberTop = number.getBoundingClientRect().top,
  start = 0,
  end = number.dataset.num;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function onScroll() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > numberTop - window.innerHeight / 2) {
    this.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      number.innerHTML = ++start;
      if (start == end) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 5);
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<p data-num="548" class="numbers">0</p>
<p data-num="548" class="numbers">0</p>
```

Comment: Looks to work when scrolling, at least to an extent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're referencing only first item even if you're querying by a class selector. You need to make your code loop through an array of elements.

Try this

```
var number = document.querySelectorAll('.numbers'),
  numberTop = number[0].getBoundingClientRect().top,
  start = 0,
  end = number[0].dataset.num;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function onScroll() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > numberTop - window.innerHeight / 2) {
    this.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      ++start;
      number.forEach( (item,index) => (item.innerHTML = start));
      if (start == end) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 5);

  }
});
```